# PyGTK Hotkey Toggle Pin/Unpin

Tags: toggle, pygtk, hotkeys

I'm still learning PyGTK, and I'm trying to figure out how I can tell the window to pin/unpin (aka toggle always on top) each time I press the F1 key.

This is what I got so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class app(gtk.Window):

  def pinning(self, widget, event) :
   if event.keyval == gtk.keysyms.F1 :
    self.set_keep_above(True)

  def __init__(self):
    super(app, self).__init__()
    self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.set_title("TestApp")
    self.set_default_size(320, 200)
    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    self.connect("key-press-event", self.pinning)
    self.show_all()

app()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: And what is your question? Does this code not work?

Comment: It pins the app, but I wanna figure out when I press it again to have it unpinned. You know the if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `get_keep_above()` method. You have to connect to the window's `window-state-event` signal; in the `event` parameter, read the `new_window_state` field to see if the sticky flag is set or not, then keep track of it yourself, for example in `self.is_kept_above`.

Then you can do

```
if self.is_kept_above:
    self.set_keep_above(False)
else:
    self.set_keep_above(True)
```

in your F1 handler.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can capture keypresses and then emit whatever signal you want, like I wrote in this answer: [PYGTK redirect event to TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603530/pygtk-redirect-event-to-treeview/6636102#6636102)